# Listing local filenames with specific extensions in directory on local website

Tags: html, jscript, filesystemobject

I have a web page on a local, networked drive. I want to list files with a .xlsm extension in a certain directory on that web page. Here's the HTML I'm using to show ALL files within a specific directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Show Local Folder File List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/JScript">
//note this is JScript, not javascript. Thus the 'type="text/JScript"' in the script tags

function ShowFolderFileList(folderspec){
var fso, f, fc, s;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec);
fc = new Enumerator(f.files);
s = "";
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
s += fc.item();
s += "<br>";
}
return s;
}

//note folder/file paths should use the local windows style backslash and be escaped '\\' :
var fileList = ShowFolderFileList('H:\\Folder1/Folder2/Folder3');
document.write(fileList);

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've done so much! Can't you add a comparison to a regex `.+(\.xlsm)$`?

Comment: Where exactly would I put that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code prints the file names via the following `for` loop, you need to match each value to the regex `.+(\\.xlsm)$`:

```
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
    if(fc.item().match(".+(\\.xlsm)$")) {
        s += fc.item();
        s += "<br>";
    }
}
```

Then your code will only print the file names that end with '.xlsm'

Comment: I think I implemented this bit of code into my existing code correctly, but now it's not showing any results.

Comment: @Robby Try to look in this similar Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1d80yhd/

Comment: That doesn't help me figure out why it's not working for me.

Comment: Maybe the items aren't strings? try: `String(fc.item()).match(".+(\\.xlsm)$")`

Comment: @Robby The JSFiddle works, so I can only conclude that the problem is somewhere else in the code. Are you sure that without the `if` condition I've added there ARE results?

Comment: Yes. I implemented the block of code you gave me into the HTML I provided in my original post. When I do that, nothing seems to happen. When I use my code, it shows all files in the directory, which include some .xlsm files.

Comment: @Robby So I'll have to see the output in order to debug this further...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163344/discussion-between-robby-and-galabra).